High level clarification of the motivation of tensor products
I am trying to reconcile the following two statements regarding the tensor product:

Tensors can be used to reduce multilinear algebra to linear algebra.

A type $(p, q)$ tensor $T$ is defined as a multilinear map


$$V\times
V\times\cdots\times V^*\times V^*\times \cdots \to \mathbb R$$
I am avoiding trying to wrestle through these concepts to invite general or conceptual answers, instead of focusing on particular mistakes in my understanding.
I don't know if the two statements above apply to tensors or tensor products, or if there is a difference. I understand that the idea is to multiply vector spaces, retaining some desirable properties. I don't know what a $\text{Hom}$ is.
But how does the tensor product reduce multilinear to linear algebra, and how is a tensor still often defined as a multilinear map if it is intended to bring down a multilinear problem to a linear one?

This is just an incorrect definition of a tensor. It only works in finite dimensions; people use it because it's more concrete than using the tensor product, but it's a fact of life in mathematics that if you want to understand what's going on at some point you just have to become comfortable with tensor products. They are a very fundamental construction!
The correct definition of a tensor of type $(p, q)$, which works in infinite dimensions, for vector bundles, etc., is that it's an element of a tensor product $V^{\otimes p} \otimes (V^{\ast})^{\otimes q}$. More generally you could say that a tensor is an element of any tensor product $V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes \dots $ of any collection of vector spaces; the term is, like "vector," potentially extremely general.
The sense in which tensor products "reduce multilinear algebra to linear algebra" (although I don't think this is really a good way to think about it) is that by the universal property of tensor products, a multilinear map, say $T : U \times V \to W$, is equivalent to a linear map $U \otimes V \to W$. The tensor product is exactly defined to make this true.
Here's an example where this has some actual content and doesn't just look tautological. If $V$ is finite-dimensional we can identify $\text{End}(V)$, the linear endomorphisms of $V$, with the tensor product $V \otimes V^{\ast}$; in other words, linear maps on $V$ are $(1, 1)$-tensors. Linear maps can be composed, and composition (matrix multiplication) is bilinear, so it is a bilinear map $\text{End}(V) \times \text{End}(V) \to \text{End}(V)$. According to the general yoga of tensors, this should correspond to a linear map
$$(V \otimes V^{\ast}) \otimes (V \otimes V^{\ast}) \to V \otimes V^{\ast}.$$
As a linear map between tensor products (which is therefore itself a tensor, of type $(3, 3)$!), matrix multiplication can be given the following alternative description: we can associate the tensor products on the LHS to rewrite it as
$$V \otimes (V^{\ast} \otimes V) \otimes V^{\ast} \to V \otimes V^{\ast}.$$
Now it can be shown that matrix multiplication is given by applying tensor contraction $V^{\ast} \otimes V \to 1$ to this middle tensor product; equivalently you can think of this as applying the dual pairing or as applying the trace on $V^{\ast} \otimes V \cong \text{End}(V)$.

Tensors are a weak point of mine, so it stood out to me when you deployed the term "tensor contraction" near the end there. Now, you gave alternatives to it as well, and I'm going to go read up on it elsewhere, but just as an FYI, it made me go "okay, now just what is tensor contraction?".

Thank you. What is "this" in "This is just an incorrect definition of a tensor"? Also, does the multilinear to linear part have to do with getting all the permutations of basis vectors, such as $e_1\otimes e_2$ and $e_2\otimes e_1$?

@Jonathan: it refers to applying the dual pairing somewhere in the middle of a big tensor product. In the explicit multidimensional array approach it corresponds to summing over a pair of a covariant and contravariant index. The reason it deserves a special name in this context is that in a big tensor product we have the freedom to apply this operation to any pair of a $V$ and a $V^{\ast}$ so just calling it the dual pairing or the trace would be a little misleading.

@JAP: you only gave one definition of a tensor ("a type $(p, q)$ tensor is defined as...") and I'm referring to that one. And no. It is just what I said; a multilinear map becomes a linear map on a tensor product.

Do you have any reference for the multilinear to linear transformation that is accessible for someone at my level?

@JAP: unfortunately I don't. It's a truly sad fact that despite how fundamental tensor products, tensors, multilinear algebra etc. are there doesn't appear to be a really good canonical reference for them, at least not one that I know.

Yes, I get exactly what you mean conceptually - it's like looking up vectors, and coming out of it thinking of tuples or arrows, instead of elements of a vector space, whatever they are (functions, etc). The multilinear to linear issue is just difficult to search for, but I understand that math is tough, and precise definitions cannot be negotiated. Since your answer is over my head in many ways, I will let people who get the explanation up-vote, and have their say.

@JAP: it would help if you asked a more specific question. There are many things to say about tensors and multilinear maps but I don't have a clear sense of what you want clarification on.
